# Wrong message when a question is closed as off topic on meta

Tags: bug, status-completed

[This question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190/codeigniter-project) was just closed as off topic because it should have been asked on the main site, not meta. The message below the question reads:

> Questions on Meta Code Review are expected to generally relate to getting feedback or review on code, within the scope defined in the faq.

Clearly this is wrong, since it applies to the main site, not meta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This close reason has been updated network wide for all meta sites.